# What good options are there for wine transport?

Tags: hiking, food

Large glass bottles just don't strike me as a "good idea" for hiking.

What options are there for carrying wine and preserving the flavor for a couple of days while hiking?

Comment: This is not worthy of an answer, but - buy boxed wines and remove the box. This leaves you with a flexible bladder containing wine with a drip-free tap. It might not be classy, but it works:-)

Comment: For extra anti-class, it's very easy to drink directly from the bladder :)

Comment: @RoryAlsop -- I need a convert to answer mod feature just for that comment ;)  Awesome idea.

Comment: It is what I always used to do when camping (before we had kids) - nowadays there are so many pairs of hands, taking cases of wine is much easier.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The key to preserving the flavor of wine is to **minimize the amount of oxygen in contact with the wine**.  One option is to use a container which is flexible, so that you can compress it in order to remove all the air inside, leaving only the wine.  Just be sure it is well sealed, so that you don’t get wine all over your backpack.  There are a few manufacturers who make containers specifically designed for this purpose, for example [this one](http://www.platypreserve.com/) or [this one](http://www.gsioutdoors.com/products/pdp/soft_sided_wine_carafe-_750_ml/).  I have never used them myself, but all the reviews I have seen are very positive.

Comment: I have used the Platypus container, and it worked just fine (kept over about 3 days). Then again, the wine was consumed very quickly... We also tried wine in a rigid Nalgene bottle on a river trip, but after a couple days it was pretty much undrinkable.

Answer (score 6):

Just for @Russell:

Buy boxed wines and remove the box. This leaves you with a flexible bladder containing wine with a drip-free tap. It might not be classy, but it works.

Most of the white wine boxes have a foil lined bladder, which also helps keep the wine cool (well, cooler.)

Comment: You can also buy wine in tetra packs. Not going to be the highest quality, but I've taken a few small ones on previous trips.